# Regarding creation of webservice client using eclipse and CXF Apache

Tags: eclipse, apache, web-services

I have a wdsl with me and have been assigned with a task to create webservice client for that using apache CXF. I would be very grateful if someone can give me a step to step insight right from setting up the applications/environment/servers to implementing the same. I am new to these concepts and finding it somewhat difficult to comprehend the information present on web. So looking for some help here as to where can i start.

Regards,
Rachael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should know uri of wsdl to generate a client. You can generate a client code in Eclipse File->New->Web Services->Web Service Client after pointing the wsdl.